# Debug website NOT in html5

Tags: html, debugging, web, web-testing

I have an html5 website, and I want to make sure it gracefully degrades if a browser doesn't support html5. I've googled for hours on end, and I've only found 1 Firefox extension that doesn't even work anymore. Can anybody suggest something to help me out here? Thanks.

Comment: "if a browser doesn't support HTML5"  Which browser do you want to support?

Comment: Anything, really. Mainly older versions of IE, I guess, because Chrome and Firefox kind of force you to upgrade, I think?

Comment: Contains relevant info: http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/semantics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running Windows, get http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

IE Tester allows you to see your site in all versions of IE.

If it degrades gracefully in IE, it'll degrade gracefully **anywhere**.

Comment: "If it degrades gracefully in IE, it'll degrade gracefully anywhere." That's wrong. Period.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 - I'm not sure he's wrong. Since IE is the worst browser on the planet, I don't know any other browser that could possibly handle anything worse.

Comment: @Rob Hm, I guess you never heard about Opera Mini

Comment: @Pumbaa80 Opera Mini doesn't run on Windows or the desktop but it still works better than IE could ever hope to.

Comment: I don't want to start a flamewar, but the question was not about windows nor desktop. Also, please note that [IE supports some good stuff that Opera Mini doesn't](http://www.caniuse.com/#agents=ie,ios_saf,op_mini,android,op_mob), like hashchange, localStorage, webfonts, contentEditable